# String formatting argument reference with item lookup

Tags: python

Is it possible to use the value of a format string argument as a key to other argument?

```
mins = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}
maxs = {'a': 12, 'b': 7, 'c': 21}

'{0} {1[{0}]} {2[{0}]}'.format('a', mins, maxs)
```

I'd expect `a 2 12` however a `KeyError: '{0}'` is thrown as the literal string `{0}` is used for the lookup and not `a`.

The lookup could be done in the call to format however I'm just after if it's possible to reference other positional arguments in the string.

```
key = 'a'
'{} {} {}'.format(key, mins[key], maxs[key])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according to the [PEP3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), you *cannot nest the replacement fields*:

> Format specifiers can themselves contain replacement fields. For
>   example, a field whose field width is itself a parameter could be
>   specified via:
>
> ```
> "{0:{1}}".format(a, b)
> ```
>
> These 'internal' replacement fields can only occur in the format
>   specifier part of the replacement field.  **Internal replacement fields
>   cannot themselves have format specifiers.**  **This implies also that
>   replacement fields cannot be nested to arbitrary levels.**

You would have to move that logic from out of the format string:

```
>>> '{0} {1} {2}'.format('a', mins['a'], maxs['a'])
'a 2 12'
```

---

However, in [Python3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html) (currently in alpha) there are the special [*format strings*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) that would help to solve it this way:

```
>>> key = "a"
>>> mins = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 3} 
>>> maxs = {'a': 12, 'b': 7, 'c': 21}
>>> f'{key} {mins[key]} {maxs[key]}'
'a 2 12'
```